# Share whatsapp link with IP address

Tags: whatsapp

I'm not sure if this is offtopic here but I found other WhatsApp questions.

If I share a link that contains an IP address like:

```
http://123.456.789.456/mystuff
```

WhatsApp make a link only for the numbers (like a phone numbers) ignoring all the remaining...
How to format it to tell it it's a whole link?

Comment: Your url is displayed correctly on my whatsapp (iPhone). Clicking on it opens Safari!

Comment: For me, whatsapp in chrome windows and on android app, doesn't color that text as a link.

Answer (score 2):

I understand this is not exactly the solution to the problem, but it might be beneficial for some people out there. All you have to do is use some sort of URL shortener.

For e.g. https://bitly.com/

It will create a shortened URL that can be shared on WhatsApp without worrying about any formatting issues.